# QuickChick not Functional

Tags: coq

I have installed QuickChick using opam using the instructions given on QuickChick's GitHub page:

https://github.com/QuickChick/QuickChick

After a successful installation, I tried to run the QuickChick tutorial

https://github.com/QuickChick/QuickChick/blob/master/examples/Tutorial.v

and Coq returned the following error message

**Error:**
Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix
<> and prefix **QuickChick**.

when I tried to process the line

From QuickChick **Require Import** QuickChick.

I'm running Coq 8.8, Opam 1.2.2, Ocaml 4.04.0 and Coq-QuickChick 1.0.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. Is there some configuration that am I missing?

Comment: Try `eval $(opam config env)` in the command line before running Coq.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed.

Comment: I just tried installing that version of quickchick in a slightly different setting (ocaml 4.06.1, opam 1.2.2), and it works for me.  What do you use to run coq?  If it is `coqtop` in a terminal window, check that `coqtop --version` says coq 8.8.0.  Also, you should have a directory `$HOME/.opam/4.04.0/lib/coq/user-contrib/QuickChick`.  If that directory does not exist, you opam installation failed.

Comment: Please use `opam list` to check what has really been installed in your current `opam` switch.  Put the result of that command in your question.

Comment: Do you have a previous installation of Coq in your system by any chance? (For example, one that was installed with apt.)

Comment: I just tried command by Li-yao Xia, on terminal and worked. Since I am use **Emacs** together with **ProofGeneral**, It didn't work.
I saw about the **opam**, and everything about this is correct.

And `opam list` said it is all installed.

Any idea how I make it work on **Emacs** with **ProofGeneral**?

Comment: I think this kind of issue is easier to resolve in a chat, e.g. using IRC (#coq channel on freenode) or Slack (#coq, https://functionalprogramming.slack.com, requires registration).